# db2 cloud or ODBC connection to R

Tags: db2, rodbc

Here i tried to setup my database service instance in ibm cloud DB2  and Access service credentials.

```
library(RODBC)
dsn_driver <- "{IBM DB2 ODBC Driver}"
dsn_database <- "bludb"            # e.g. "bludb"
dsn_hostname <- "b1bc1829-6f45-4cd4-bef4-10cf081900bf.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud" # e.g "54a2f15b-5c0f-46df-8954-.databases.appdomain.cloud"
dsn_port <- "32304"   # e.g. "32733" 
dsn_protocol <- "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid <- "xxxxxxxxx"        # e.g. "zjh17769"
dsn_pwd <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"      # e.g. "zcwd4+8gbq9bm5k4"  
dsn_security <- "ssl"
```

Then i Create a database connection

Create a connection string and connect:

```
conn_path <- paste("DRIVER=",dsn_driver,
                     ";DATABASE=",dsn_database,
                     ";HOSTNAME=",dsn_hostname,
                     ";PORT=",dsn_port,
                     ";PROTOCOL=",dsn_protocol,
                     ";UID=",dsn_uid,
                     ";PWD=",dsn_pwd,
                     ";SECURITY=",dsn_security,        
                     sep="")
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(conn_path)
```

but here i got this warning msg that the connection is field:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(conn_path) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(conn_path) : ODBC connection failed
```

as i took the credentials information from the same cloud server as the below pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAb6h.png)

thank you

Hello i have question , i struggled when i try to connect the database in DB2 cloud to local R server , so i am a beginner and i found the steps for this are very mixed up so i downloaded the data bases to the DB2 cloud then i need to connect these datasets to R to do the sql functions as it requested in my course for IBM,

Comment: Please edit your question to add text (not pictures). What is your version of R? Are you using Rstudio (or similar).  Please write the Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows/cloud)  and the Db2-server version.  Your R will connect to the Db2 database as long as the odbcadm32 tool is able to connect to the same database.  You need to understand how to configure your data source. This is explained in Db2 documentation.

Comment: i used R-studio , R-4.1.3. and i created Db2 cloud

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as i mentioned above i want to establish the connection between R and ibm cloud Db2

Comment: @HAJ Look carefully at the new error message, it tells you that your port number has a bad format, remove the `"<"` before the port-number. The separator between the tokens in the connection string needs to be `;` and the last character in the connection string should also be `;`

Comment: Hello @mao , i tried to do what you mentioned about commas, its doesn't work, then the problem still shown up with ((can't find the data source)) even i took the credentials information ??  (( i edit the code above pleas give it a look))

Comment: pls any helllp???